# Apple accepts the same build

Tags: ios, iphone

I have submitted my app on iTunes Connect Individual account the last year. So, it is in iTunes now. I want to use the same code build to submit the app in iTunes Connect Organization account. What my point is if I use the same build to submit the app, will Apple accept my app? If not what is the reason?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=6112013c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want transfer your app, Your app will be there in two account. It will lead to reject your binary according to duplication.

According to Section 2.11 of the [App Store Review Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html).

you can see this line..

> Apps that duplicate apps already in the App Store may be rejected, particularly if there are many of them, such as fart, burp, flashlight, and Kama Sutra apps

But  you can take advantage with your old code by below.

> Re skinned template apps that simply duplicate content and/or
>   functionality create clutter, diminish the overall experience for the
>   end user, and reduce the ability of developers to market their
>   applications. This is not in compliance with the App Store Review
>   Guidelines.

Comment: @user3040319 Yes, You can do :) Be careful with Design which must differ with your existing ..

Answer (score 1):

There should be no problem with that - if only you change bundle ID.

But better idea is to transfer existing project to another account - than you don't have to wait for review process.

https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=6112013c

Comment: Thanks but i dont want to transfer app

Answer (score 0):

I take it you want to remove the original app from iTunes, so there shouldn't be any problem with duplication at all - but you should remove it before submitting the new one of course :-).